# Why is hover pushing the content down?

Tags: html, css

If you hover over the menu over on [this website](http://sportrusten.nl) you see that the content is pushed down. I inherited the stylesheet from other people and it's a complete mess. Can anyone please explain to me why this hover is pushing down the content?

The menu is built as followed:

`li > ul class .sub-menu > li > a class .sub_menu_item`

I looked at the `position` and `display` CSS but I can't seem to find anything strange. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should look into using a debugger like firebug to test problems and solutions. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I check hover on first li in the 'three columns' div you can inspect the dropdown and see that it inherits the default "position: 'relative'".

You want to apply the styling "Position: 'absolute'" on the ul class="sub-menu", which will make it effectively in its own container so it can go mostly where it wants, so you have greater control of its positioning. This is unless a parent of it has the setting "position: 'relative'", which it will then follow the boundaries of that containing cell).

Heads up also - it looks like you'll need to increase the width or something for the border-radius on the right hand side of the dropdown cells if you apply position absolute.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation! Can't believed I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

add this line into your css file:

```
#navigation ul.sub-menu{
     position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Some explanations would be great for the asker.

Answer (score 2):

The `.sub-menu` elements are not given a position so they remain in the document flow when they are shown. They need a `position: absolute` to remove them from the flow and prevent content shift.